# Protractor + Selenium Grid: Shard Test Specs Across Nodes

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, protractor, selenium-grid

I recently setup a Selenium Grid (1 server for the hub, and 10 other servers which host 1 node each), and I have no issues running my Protractor automated tests. However, I'd like to shard my ~400 tests across all the nodes defined in `multiCapabilities` (within my protractor.conf.js) so I can dramatically decrease the execution time.

Protractor once [supported this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/569), but it has since been deprecated (not sure why..?). I've tried setting `shardTestFiles: true` in the `multiCapabilities` object, but that just sharded tests across all browser instances within each node (every node ran all the tests). I played with the `maxSessions`, `maxInstances` and `count` configurations as well. I even tried removing `multiCapabilities` and putting the complete configuration in `capabilities` - no luck.

Is there a *non-hacky* way to get this working? I've scoured npm, and I can't find any node modules or gulp plugins for this either.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: It worked just fine. Nice write-up...
http://blog.yodersolutions.com/run-protractor-tests-in-parallel/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try giving multicapabilties something like below in conf.js

multiCapabilities: [{
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 2
    specs : ['specs1', 'specs2'],
  },
{
    'browserName': 'firefox',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 2,
     specs : ['specs3', 'specs4'],
  },
}]

This will run specs1 and 2 only on chrome and specs 3 and 4 on firefox and this reduces the total time.of execution by 50%.
You can pass more capabilities inside multicapabilities and distribute specs further to those capabilities to reduce the total execution time further more.